# "cannot collect variable"?

Tags: c, debugging, segmentation-fault, gdb, clion

What does it mean: "Cannot collect variables" ? How can I fix it ? It makes the debugger won't report values.

[image]

I'm trying to call my function

`write_argument2(argc,  * argv, * string[0]);`

I'm going to change and rearrange `argv`. My variable `string` is `char **string[100][100];` and maybe that is not ideal. The string variable is going to update `argv` with new arguments:

```
void write_argument2(int argc, char argv[], char *string[]) {
    int j = 0;
    for (j = 0; j <  argc; j++) {
        if (argv[j])
             string[j] = strdup(&argv[j]);
    }
}
```

But I've done something wrong and it crashes. The error says "cannot collect variable" and a segmentaion fault for `strdup`.

I also tried the following which compiles but also becomes a segmentation fault: `* string[j] = * strdup( & argv[j]);`

Gdb says:

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11-0ubuntu1) 7.11
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./shell...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/dac/ClionProjects/shell2/openshell/shell 
'PATH' is set to /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin.
$ ls

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000403b1a in write_argument2 (string=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>, 
    argc=<optimized out>) at main.c:147
147              string[j] = strdup( &argv[j]);
(gdb)
```

Should I use `strcpy` instead or change some declarations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `argv` is an array of strings(`char *argv[]`), it's not a char array. If your string is defined as `char string[100][100];`, that is, its storage is defined to be arrays, you can do the following:

```
void write_argument2(int argc, char *argv[], char string[][100]) {
    int j = 0;
    for (j = 0; j <  argc; j++) {
        if (argv[j])
             strcpy(string[j], argv[j]);
    }
}
```

But this is subject to crash if `argv` has more strings than the number of `string`, that is 100, or anyone element of the `argv` is longer than 99. so you could also do dynamic allocation:

```
char **write_argument2(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char **string = malloc(argc * sizeof(char*));
    int j = 0;
    for (j = 0; j <  argc; j++) {
        if (argv[j])
             string[j] = strdup(argv[j]);
    }
    return string;
}
```

EDIT: add a test program to demonstrate for OP:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **write_argument2(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char **string = malloc(argc * sizeof(char*));
    int j = 0;
    for (j = 0; j <  argc; j++) {
        if (argv[j])
             string[j] = strdup(argv[j]);
    }
    return string;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    char **string = write_argument2(argc, argv);
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, string[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Calling this problem:

```
$ ./a.out a bb ccc dddd
0: ./a.out
1: a
2: bb
3: ccc
4: dddd
```

Comment: @Montao that allocation is wrong, `strlen(strdup(argv[j]))` is the length of the string `argv[j]`, it's not the number of strings in the array. Why not post the code that calls the function?

Comment: `string= write_argument2(argc,  argv);` is the code that calls the function.

Comment: Yes it works. But I need also to update the variable. Do I have to use realloc? I can ask a new question about a new function. It looks strange but I think I might have to do something like `char *** write_command2(int w, int argc, const char *argv[], const char **string[])` to update something in a matrix and use the variable `char ** string[]` as a dynamic matrix that can grow.

Comment: I posted another question how to update with realloc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37020409/how-can-i-resolve-a-segmentation-fault

Comment: @Montao What kind of update are you making? like appending another string?

Comment: I have to use a matrix. Now I have a memory leak because of this update: `  string[w]= malloc(argc * sizeof(char*));` And `***` three star pointers. `char *** write_command2(int w, int argc, const char *argv[], char **string[]) {` with return type ` string[w]= malloc(argc * sizeof(char*));` and how to `free()`